# Postgresql error on a deployed rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, linode

I have a rails app I am currently working on. I have deployed to a linode server using ubuntu 12.10 and am getting a lovely "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message. I have been looking inside the log files for any indication what could be wrong, but nothing appears to be throwing an error.

Known

1. Works locally in both development and production mode
2. Error logs says nothing other then accessing the database
3. rake db:migrate database configuration does not specify adapter
4. RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create results in password authentication failed for user "deployer"
5. user/owner inside postgresql is "tasks" and the password matches what I have inside database.yml

I have been looking around stackoverflow trying to find any related errors, but I have not found a solution that works.

Thanks in advance for your time.

.

```
deployer@Asphodel:~/apps/TaskWebsite/current$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "deployer"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "deployer"
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `initialize'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `new'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `connect'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:107:in `rescue in create_database'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:51:in `create_database'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/TaskWebsite/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"tasks_production", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "user"=>"tasks", "password"=>"blahblah"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the production configuration look like in your database.yml? It looks like the user specified there is "deployer", which would be incorrect if the user in the cluster is "tasks" like you mentioned.  If the username and password there is correct, I would start troubleshooting by trying to connect to the cluster via some other client - my personal preference is to just use the psql utility.  You can connect like this (assuming psql is in your path) -

```
psql -h localhost -U deployer postgres
```

The "postgres" database is created by default in a new data cluster.  Once you can get connected with a different client, update the production config in your database.yml with whatever changes are necessary and try again.

Comment: Thank you. The command allowed me to monkey around with the settings. I removed the tasks user and recreated a database under the deployer user. Once I did that, I no longer had the issues with the mismatch passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Stab in the dark... guessing that 'deployer' is the OS user? What's Postgres's pg_hba.conf file look like?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Perhaps you are only allowing 'peer' from localhost?  Take a look at the section that looks like the below in particular...

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your local unix user does not have permission to your postgresql socket.  To fix this, you should grant local access, edit `/etc/postgresql/main/pg_hba.conf` and after the comment about  # "local" add this:

```
local all         all                 trust
```

This will grant access to all local users on this machine.

Save the file and restart Postgresql - you should be good to go.